# Is this function a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis

\begin{equation}
[ f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x^2       & \quad x>0\\
    1/2  & \quad x=0
  \end{cases}
]
\end{equation}

Is this function convex?
Is the epigraph of this function a convex set?

I think this function is convex in $[0,+\infty)$, but I do not think the epigraph of this function a convex set. I'm really confused.

Comment: If you think that the epigraph is not a convex set, then you're saying that there are a pair of points $A$ and $B$ where the line segment $\overline{AB}$ is not contained in the epigraph. Do you really think you can find a pair of points like this?

Comment: A = (0,0), B = (0,1/2), Is the line segment $\overline{AB}$ contained in the epigraph?

Comment: Is $(0, 0)$ a point in the epigraph though? It isn't above a point on the graph.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your great answer!